# Uncaught Error: Class 'Phar' not found

Tags: magento2, admin, magento2.3.3

After installed **Magento 2.3.3**, I try login Admin account and have this issue:

[image]

I use **Magento 2.3.3** and **PHP 7.3.13**.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm also getting the same error, I did resolved it by installing **phar** by executing `apt-get install php-phar`

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 3):

**Run This Command :-**

```
composer update
```

**After you ran the above command, you can run the command:**

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

Comment: Thank you! I can run composer update. Do you have any idea http://prntscr.com/qbxtcs?

Comment: apt-get install php-phar

Comment: Thank you for your help!